# Limit results to 10 in redis with node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, redis

I have a set of values I retrieve from redis, and send it over to the client as json:

```
  members.hgetall(All,_)
```

I'm using streamline js by the way.

I guess getting something like MYSQL "LIMIT" command would be great also for the node redis library :)

Comment: Please show us the code, and explain what you mean by "doesn't work".  Specifically, what you expect to see, and what you see instead.

Comment: Oh man, I've made a js lib to to this and other queries to arrays, but I've lost it when I left my old job. I regret not making a copy every time I look at js array.
If I manage to write it again (it was fairly simple), I'll answer your question with a link to it.

Comment: it just returns undefined....i try  members.hgetall(All,_).slice(0,10)

Comment: What does hgetall() return without the slice()?

Comment: it returns a json object ex : { '1':'John Smith', '2':'Bill Smith'}

Comment: I realize that a better solution would be to limit redis to only return 10 results like MYSQL

Comment: OK, that's not an array so that's why you can't use slice. Using that object you could easily create an array of no more than 10 items. Will the property names always go up in sequence starting at "1"?

Answer (score 1):

To get the first 10 values of an array, you would use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
var firstTenArray = myArray.slice(0, 10);
```

Both parameters are zero-based indices for start and end. Start is index 0 (first element) and end is index 10 (11th element), since slice does not include the last element in the returned set.

Comment: Second parameter would need to be 10, because slice() extracts up to but not including the specified end index.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me, I'm using redis json to store and fetch json objects. In nodejs make use of the following function. Add the path where your array attriburte lies followed by [0:10] the offset and limit.

```
let values = await redis.json.get(:key, {
            path: [
                '$.[0:10]'
            ]
        });
console.log(values)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to slice() is the end index, so you should try slice(0, 9).

Comment: This isn't right: the second parameter _is_ the end index, but it extracts up to but not including that index. So (0,10) is correct to get the first ten items.